# What is the 'NB' sigil in the LoL Worlds Video?

Tags: league-of-legends

There is a sigil that shows up often in the clip. Here's an image:

[image]

Thing is, even if I know the LoL iconography pretty well, this sigil means nothing to me.

So is it a chinese/korean character of some sort? Some brand (tought it could be a new logo of New Balance, but that doesn't seem to stick)? Or is it something Worlds Related that was not announced yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spotify behind the scenes identify it as the M/B mark, which makes it easy to think that it's MAKE/BREAK that is the slogan of worlds this year.

[image]